# how to resolve the build path error in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, error-handling, build, path, cucumber

Am getting the below error when I run the project.
**Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-1.7. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment. **
I have installed and set the system variable to JDK 20.
I have set the compliance level to 20.
[Build path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O569R.png)

Anyone PLEASE help resolve this issue at the earliest.

Comment: In the _Libraries_ tab select the _JRE System Library_ node, hit _Edit..._ and choose `JavaSE-20` (assuming in _Project > Properties: Java Compiler_ you have _Use compliance from execution environment_ enabled and also assuming you do not use Maven or Gradle).